# Unable to set the current stack frame

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I opened the command window in Visual Studio 2015 CTP and given the following command

```
>k ef migration add [migration name]
>k ef migration apply
```

It is giving the response message as `Unable to set the current stack frame.`

How to solve the above issue.

I am Scaffolding a new migration for the pending model changes and applying them to the database from the command line.

I am following on **[View components and Inject in ASP.NET MVC 6](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/vc#cnp)**

Answer (score 0):

In an administrator command window, change the directory to the project directory. The project directory contains the project.json file.

Then run the commands from there.
So in short, don't use the visual command window, but an actual windows command window.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these steps to install the K command:

Install the K Version Manager (KVM)

```
Open a command prompt with Run as administrator.
Run the following command:
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/master/kvminstall.ps1'))"

The script installs KVM for the current user.
Exit the command prompt window and start another as an administrator (you need to start a new command prompt to get the updated path environment).
Upgrade KVM with the following command:
KVM upgrade
You are now ready to run EF migrations.
```

The source is your shared link ["View components and Inject in ASP.NET MVC 6"](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/vc#cnp)

Than you need to run commands at cmd.exe